# PHP weird session data in file, cannot unserialize

Tags: php, session

I need to share sessions between subdomain but my sessions are stored in weird format. For example if ill compare same session data (from session file) from different servers i see that in first case data are stored correctly but not in second one.

First server session string:

```
TEST_VAR|s:10:"TEST VALUE";
```

Second server session string:

```
NUnNmu-NLaO2lP-1J_LVRdJm5cPH54dlnDN1W1GaHXrebf3hl_clOl3xeoZlvHsj
```

I'm using same code to generate sessions, where is the problem? Anyone know whats wrong? How can i decode this weird string? `session_decode()` can't handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help: [PHP / Drupal, Session Storage and encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1005041/php-drupal-session-storage-and-encryption)

If not, check the php.ini/`phpinfo()` on both servers and see if there are any differences in the session-related configuration.

Comment: Exactly, great link. 2nd one must be a hardened suhosin install.

Comment: Thank you very much. Problem resolved. suhosin.session.encrypt = Off